# Why does my progress bar only update in Firefox?

Tags: html, progress-bar

Three progress bars, all work on Firefox, but the first does not work on Safari, Chrome or Opera:

```html
    <div class="serverStats">
        <p>
            <progress value=" <%= movies %>" max="<%= filesExpected %>">
                <div class="progress-bar">
                    <span>Movies(click 'Save'): <%= movies %></span>
                </div>
            </progress>
        </p>
        <p>
            <progress value="<%= xmls %>" max="<%= filesExpected %>">
                <div class="progress-bar">
                    <span>XML files: <%= xmls %></span>
                </div>
            </progress>
        </p>
        <p>
            <progress value="<%= images %>" max="<%= filesExpected %>">
                <div class="progress-bar">
                    <span>Images: <%= images %></span>
                </div>
            </progress>
        </p>
        <p>Folders: <%= folders %>, Files: <%= filesExpected %></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason (after much head scratching) is a typo in the value for the first progress bar - there is a rogue leading-space in there.

I did not realise the impact could be so great and that it would vary from one browser to the next.